# Update document url in easyXDM

Tags: javascript, sockets, iframe, cross-domain, easyxdm

How can I dynamically update the consumer's location using [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM)?

I've tried the following code without success.

**Provider**

```
var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
  onReady: function(){
    socket.postMessage("update-remote");
  },
  onMessage: function(message, origin) {
   alert("received " + message + " from " + origin);
  }
});
```

**Consumer**

```
var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
  remote: "http://remotedomain/page1.html",
  remoteHelper: "http://remotedomain/name.html",
  onReady: function(){
    socket.postMessage("foo-message");
  },
  onMessage: function(message, origin) {
   if(message="update-remote") {
     this.remote = "http://remotedomain/page2.html",
   }
   alert("received " + message + " from " + origin);
  }
});
```